# Evaluating a function inside php with if

Tags: php, json, if-statement, foreach

Im trying to do a loop through a pretty large json file with this function someone else helped me with. But the code below returns with : `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

This code is executed before the function:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("bdfile/summoner_leagues_entries_export.json");
while (!$file->eof()) 
{   
    $json = json_decode($file->fgets(), true);
    var_dump($json);
}
```

_

```
function getentry($json)
{
        foreach($json as $league)
        {
                if($league['queue'] == 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5')
                {
                  return $league['entries'][0];
                }

        return null;
        }
}
$entry = getentry($json);
if(isset($entry)) echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ',' . "</br>";
```

this is the output of `var_dump($json);` (just a tiny example because its a large file):

```
    {
  "_id" : ObjectId("540449a4f59600af7d285075"),
  "leagues" : [{
      "name" : "Cassiopeia's Hunters",
      "tier" : "GOLD",
      "queue" : "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "21893177",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "JoKoksa",
          "division" : "III",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(5),
          "wins" : NumberLong(99),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : false,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(21893177)
    }, {
      "name" : "Kayle's Patriots",
      "tier" : "BRONZE",
      "queue" : "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-ffbaccc0-b8c0-11e2-b67a-782bcb497d6f",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "EloStechers",
          "division" : "II",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(64),
          "wins" : NumberLong(9),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : false,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(21893177)
    }, {
      "name" : "Cassiopeia's Infiltrators",
      "tier" : "BRONZE",
      "queue" : "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-ffbaccc0-b8c0-11e2-b67a-782bcb497d6f",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "EloStechers",
          "division" : "II",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(60),
          "wins" : NumberLong(11),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : true,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(21893177)
    }],
  "summonerId" : NumberLong(21893177),
  "region" : "euw",
  "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1412719896)
}
```

EDIT 3:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("bdfile/summoner_leagues_entries_export.json");
    while (!$file->eof()) {

        $json = json_decode($file->fgets(), true);

            foreach($json['leagues'] as $entry) {

            echo $entry['entries'][0]['playerOrTeamName']  . ',' . $entry['tier'] . ',' . $entry['entries'][0]['division'] . ',' . $entry['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'] . ',' . $entry['entries'][0]['wins'] . "<br/>";

            }
    }

$file = null;
```

**EDIT 4:**

I got it fixed, if you are interested, i can paste code here.

Comment: that is odd, you already got it decoded and after var dumping you got another json string?

Comment: I dont know, im just trying to evaluate the Warning: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` which drives me crazy.

Comment: fck, i noticed that this is just a dump from mongodb which uses bson. you can see that on the `NumberLong()`. But this should not be the reason why foreach is not working right? I succesfully parsed json from the same file WITHOUT the if statement. But when i use the if statement with that foreach, the code stops working. Look in main code under `EDIT 3` for working code on same JSON file.

Comment: nobody able to help me out on this?

Comment: unless each line of your input file is a solitary isolated json-encoded string (e.g. the entire of a json_encode() call result on a single line of text), then your fgets() loop is going to be reading "corrupted" json,b ecause it's only reading a small one-line subset of a larger json string.

Comment: @Marc B, http://pastebin.com/2S7cJSaw (working code for my situation)

Answer (score 0):

I think your line in getentry($json)

```
foreach($json as $league)
```

should be

```
foreach($json['leagues'] as $league)
```

Comment: I tried changing it, but gave same result, unfortunately.      `foreach($json['leagues'] as $league)`

Answer (score 0):

On reflection. That doesn't look like a vardump. Probably $json is just a string when you get into getentry.

Perhaps you need a bson_decode function before you will be able to treat it like a hash (array)

json_decode won't handle it.

There is one in mongo for php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bson-decode.php

But it does say "This function is very beta and entirely useless for 99% of users. It is only useful if you're doing something weird, such as writing your own driver on top of the PHP driver."